# Undefined operator '.^' for input arguments of type 'dataset' - MatLab

Tags: matlab, cosine-similarity

I have this matlab function to calculate the cosine similarity between 60 vectors of a dataset. 60 rows correspond to the vector number and 2 columns to the x and y components of each vector.

```
function [cosSim] = cosineSimilarity(data)

[n_row n_col] = size(data);

norm_r = sqrt(sum(abs(data).^2,2));

for i = 1:n_row
    for j = i:n_row
        cosSim(i,j) = dot(data(i,:), data(j,:)) / (norm_r(i) * norm_r(j));
        cosSim(j,i) = cosSim(i,j);
    end
end
end
```

The main script:

```
cd(matlabroot)
cd('help/toolbox/stats/examples')
ds = dataset('XLSFile','TestCosSim.xlsx');

c = cosineSimilarity(ds);
```

When I run the script, I get the following errors:

```
Undefined operator '.^' for input arguments of type 'dataset'.

Error in cosineSimilarity (line 8)
norm_r = sqrt(sum(data.^2,2));

Error in CosSimTest (line 6)
c = cosineSimilarity(ds);
```

Does anybody have an idea of why this is happening?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What is the version of your Matlab?

Comment: Try `c = cosineSimilarity(double(ds));`

Comment: Thanks a lot Ander, it worked!